# Conditional Formatting based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am running an Elimination pool for the Premier League and I'm trying to track the teams picked from week to week.

I have a list of all the teams in the Premier League listed under each person in the pool. I then have a list of each week's picks. If a team was picked this week I would like that team's cell to turn red with a strikethrough.

https://monosnap.com/file/MUPxy2Lqv9H4lMbiPNmp2ReAvUXjk1

I've tried doing conditional Formatting: 
Range: A2:A21 
Custom formula is: =B25

But it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if the first 21 rows are moved across one column to the right. I'd show you how but posting your data as an image only is inconsiderate and I can't be bothered. However then selecting Rows1:21 and applying a CF formula rule of:

```
=A1=index(A$25:A,match("zzz",A$25:A))
```

with formatting of your choice should work.